# Code mod/shift to refactor rxjs subscribe method

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs

Does anyone have or know of a code mod or refactoring plugin for VS Code that will refactor multiple subscribe arguments into one argument object? I have many existing observables using multiple arguments, but that has been deprecated. It would be very nice if there was an automated refactor for this conversion.

See https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Most often people just have this format in their code.

```
of([1,2,3]).subscribe((success) => {...}, (err) => {...} );
```

which would convert to

```
of([1,2,3]).subscribe({ next: (success) => {...}, error: (err) => {...}} );
```

Comment: you can write a regular expression to refactor in search and replace

Comment: FYI (from your link): "_In short we deprecated all signatures where you specified an anonymous error or complete callback and passed an empty function to one of the callbacks before_". So your current implementation `.subscribe((success) => {...}, (err) => {...} )` isn't deprecated but implementations such as `.subscribe(null, (err) => {...} )` are.

Comment: @ruth From the link (in bold). _"We have deprecated all signatures of subscribe that take more than 1 argument."_

Comment: @Ulfius: Agreed. I misinterpreted the statement that I quoted. Arguably it's quite ambiguous. From the [source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L76):"_Signatures taking separate callback arguments will be removed in v8_". So the signature taking only a single callback for the `next` notification is not deprecated (not yet atleast). Your implementation with `next` and `error` callbacks is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this transformer with [jscodeshift](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift)

**transform_rxjs_6_to_7.js**

```js
module.exports = function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  // Find all method calls to `subscribe`
  root.find(j.CallExpression, {
    callee: {
      property: {name: 'subscribe'}
    },
    arguments: args =>
      args.length == 0
      || (args.length > 0 && !j.ObjectExpression.check(args[0]))
  }).replaceWith(path => {
    const {node} = path;

    // Wrap the argument in an object with `next` property
    const properties = [];
    if (node.arguments.length > 0) {
      properties.push(
        j.property('init', j.identifier('next'), node.arguments[0]));
    }
    if (node.arguments.length > 1) {
      properties.push(
        j.property('init', j.identifier('error'), node.arguments[1]));
    }
    if (node.arguments.length > 2) {
      properties.push(
        j.property('init', j.identifier('complete'), node.arguments[2]));
    }
    node.arguments = [j.objectExpression(properties)];

    return node;
  });

  return root.toSource();
};
```

and run it with

```bash
npx jscodeshift --parser ts --transform=transform_rxjs_6_to_7.js --extensions=js,ts src
```